# The GenerateStaticWebAsssetsPropsFile task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have .NET 6 solution, with about 40 projects. 
When building the solution I am getting the following error

```
The "GenerateStaticWebAsssetsPropsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\..\SolutionName\ProjectName\obj\Debug\net6.0\staticwebassets\msbuild.MyProjectName.Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.props'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tasks.GenerateStaticWebAsssetsPropsFile.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

The interesting thing is that this error is reported to be in the
 `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.Pack.targets` file

I notice that the path reporting `7.0.100` but all of my projects are targeting .NET 6.

I do not know if this is the reason or not,
I updated VisualStudio 2 days ago, and I downloaded .NET 7, but I did not change the Target of the project, so I am a little bit confused why .NET 7 is used.
or if any of this is related to the problem I am having that is preventing me from building the solution

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Too long filepath**. 
Make the project name shorter, or move it to a folder with shorter names. 
*This problem actually appeared with the Visual Studio update*

Comment: yes, I copied the project to a path, that is shorter than the current one, and the problem has been solved. Thank you

Comment: I have upgraded to Visual Studio 17.7.0 Preview 1.0 and the issue remains, is this going to be fixed?

Comment: That's strange, anyway I have relocated the parent folder source\repos under C:\ and changed the Location into VisualStudio->Tools.

Comment: I have updated VS today and I still have the same issue :(

Comment: This worked for me. Moved the project to   shorter path and all good. Cheers

Comment: Give this man a beer! Thank you!